# How do I add media to a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, media-library

I want to add some custom fields to allow a user to select items from the Media library for the custom post (in the add/edit view)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer will be in the form of links.

The WPAlchemy meta box class supports this: http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/
+ tutorial http://www.farinspace.com/wordpress-media-uploader-integration/

A tutorial on how to do it, mainly javascript: http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/

Comment: thats cool. I dont really like the idea of having someone elses classes on there. just a simple howto. but i guess this works

Answer (score 1):

You could add

```
<a href="#" class="button insert-media add_media" data-editor="content" title="Add Media">
    <span class="wp-media-buttons-icon"></span> Add Media
</a>
```

to a metabox

Comment: In order for that to be useful you'd need the code for catching the selected file as a form value.